# bootstrap menu not closing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

the menu opens but doesn't close I can't quite figure out what the problem is I would appreciate it if you could help?i've tried many ways, but I haven't been able to

```
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navi" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      mini service
     </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="./4.html">4</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="./3.html">3</a>
     </div>
   </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the button, have experienced it too a couple of times, try to remove all JavaScript links and just link the javascript.min.js alone and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use he bootstrap bundle.js only as the following:

***this link for css file used it inside the head tag***

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

***this you can use it before the body close tag.***

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```